# embed xml in custom controls

Tags: c#, xml, dll, custom-controls, web-controls

i create a **custom Control** and using the **XML** file now i need to have just one dll file to use that to another project can you help me to embed xml file to my custom control project?

my programming language is c#.net

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio (My version is 2008, if you have 2010, this might be slightly different.)

1. Open properties for your DLL project.
2. Click the Resources tab.
3. Click the blue link (if there is one to add resources to your DLL).
4. Top Left with the little down arrow choose files.
5. Click Add Resource, find your file and add it. Give it a name like `XmlFile` with no dots, this is your handle to the file.
6. Save and Close Properties for the DLL.

Then somewhere in your project you will use this line, or something like it to access your file.

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.XmlFile);
```